# Adding a div containing data around a li on mouseover?

Tags: html, hover

I have a normal li element, it contains a picture. Now when I hover it, it should be surrounded by a div for example which contains some descriptions for the image in the li. Please check out this link http://www.zalando.de/damenschuhe-sandaletten/  and hover the shoes. As you see, it adds information around the image.

I tried several things but the results are not really what I want. Any ideas how to to that in a good way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add an border to the li on hover, and give the image an alt title. Same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="info">Info 1</div>
        [Image 1]
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="info">Info 2</div>
        [Image 2]
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="info">Info 3</div>
        [Image 3]
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="info">Info 4</div>
        [Image 4]
    </li>
</ul>

ul{
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    background: #ddd;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
li > .info{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-40px;
    width:35px;
    height:100%;
    background:#ffa;
}
li:hover{
    background:#ccf;
    border:5px solid #afa;
    margin:5px;
}
li:hover > .info{
    display:block;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/NhfF3/

Comment: Yeah, that comes pretty close! Let me see if it works for my case ... thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

you should add a hidden `div` inside the `li` element. http://jsfiddle.net/SKxjM/

this is the CSS

```
.expandable .expansion { display: none; }
.expandable:hover .expansion { display: inline; }
```

And the HTML should look like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="expandable">this is expandable
        <div class="expansion">more info</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the CSS :after tag with content.

```
<li>
    <img src="whatever.jpg">
</li>


li:hover:after{
    content: 'image caption here';
}
```

Also, you could dynamically add it, if that makes it work for your site easier:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('li:hover:after', 'content: \'image caption here\'');
```

Comment: The after selector wont work, I need to add information everywhere around the image.